# Why can't I read all of the values in the matrix in scilab?

Tags: file-io, scilab

i am trying to read a csv file  and my code is as follows

```
param=csvRead("C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\VOA-BK code\assets\Iris.csv",",","%i",'double',[],[],[1 2 3 4]); //reads number of clusters and features
data=csvRead("C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\VOA-BK code\assets\Iris.csv",",","%f",'double',[],[],[3 1 19 4]); //reads the values


numft=param(1,1);//save number of features
numcl=param(2,1);//save number of clusters
data_pts=0;
data_pts = max(size(data, "r"));//checks how many number of rows 
disp(data(numft-3:data_pts,:));//print all data points (I added -3 otherwise it displays only 15 rows)

disp(numft);//print features
disp(data_pts);//print features
disp(param);

endfunction
```

below is the values that i am trying to read

```
features,4,,
clusters,3,,
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2
4.9,3,1.4,0.2
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2
5,3.6,1.4,0.2
7,3.2,4.7,1.4
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5
5.5,2.3,4,1.3
6.5,2.8,4.6,1.5
5.7,2.8,4.5,1.3
6.3,3.3,6,2.5
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9
7.1,3,5.9,2.1
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8
6.5,3,5.8,2.2
7.6,3,6.6,2.1
```

I do not know why the code only displays 15 rows instead of 17. The only time it displays the correct matrix is when i put -3 in numft but with that, the number of columns would be 1. I am so confused. Is there a better way to read the values?

Comment: It may be a problem that some of these are formatted differently. Column one only has true double variables marked with a dot like `3.1` whereas column two has integers such as `3`. 

Maybe they need to be in the form of `3.0`, but that is just a wild guess.

Comment: Before asking a new question please validate the answer you had to the previous one. Otherwise nobody will answer your future questions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the csvRead call in the  first line of your script the boundaries of the region to read is incorrect, it should be corrected like this:

```
param=csvRead("C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\VOA-BK code\assets\Iris.csv",",","%i",'double',[],[],[1 2 2 2]);
```